# How to stop the results of a jquery php load being cached

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a new problem which MUST affect practically every person who uses AJAX. I have a HTML/JavaScript page which (using a jQuery call) loads a `.php` into my page - but it seems to cache the results and often just returns the cached information rather than re-running the PHP script.

The code below is how I'm trying to overcome the problem (thanks bazmegakapa for the code - I've just tried to add the cache:flase bit - but it doesn't seem to work).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    cache: false
    $('#selecthere').load('/temp/php_script.php', function () { //callback
        $('select', this).change(function () { //catch onchange event of select
            //call your function here, pass the selected value
            initialize($(this).val());
        });
    });
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a random number to the end

```
var random = Math.random() * 10;
$('#selecthere').load('/temp/php_script.php?r=' + random, function () {
```

Comment: Yeah this is right, i faced the same problem one time and this is how I solved it.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks folks.

Comment: Or maybe the current time in milliseconds, which is more likely to be different from the cached value.

Answer (score 3):

Your php_script.php file should send the correct headers to prevent caching.

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm guessing this is the CORRECT way to do it, so I'm going to vote for it, but I've actaully implemented JohnP's answer, and it seems to work, so I'm accepting that one. Thanks again!

Comment: [`post-check=0, pre-check=0` does not make any sense](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/06/01/613132.aspx): “[…] setting both values to 0 had absolutely no effect in IE5 or IE6.” And “[…] we’ve taken a fix for IE7 Beta 3 to ignore both extensions if either is set equal to zero.”

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing the cache: false wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax('/temp/php_script.php', 
       { 
           cache: false, 
           success: function(result) {
               $('#selecthere').html(result);
           }
       }
    );
});
```